# Why does the compiler infer the lifetime of a parameter only in some cases

Tags: rust

The below code does not compile as expected from [Lifetime Elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) described in "The Book".

```
fn f1() -> &str {
    "will not compile"
}
```

When I explicitly add the static lifetime to the output lifetime parameter, it works as expected -

```
fn f2() -> &'static str {
    "compiles as expected"
}
```

But I am surprised why the below code compiles without errors -

```
fn f3<'a>() -> &'a str {
    "Why does this compile"
}
```

To my understanding `f3` merely gives a name to the lifetime of the return value. It doesn't introduce any relationship to other defined lifetimes. I assume some kind of automatic inferencing is made by the compiler that the lifetime is indeed static. But my question is why doesn't the compiler do the same for `f1`? Did I really provide more context to the compiler by converting `f1` to `f3`?

Comment: Just to be clear, `f1` doesn't fail to compile because the compiler can't figure out what's going on. It knows the returned `&str` is `&'static`; it simply refuses to have anonymous lifetimes in the return type that aren't tied to the lifetime of an input (presumably because it's not clear where the lifetime would be derived from in that case). Making `f3` generic explicitly says that the caller gets to decide. Then all the compiler has to check is that any decision is valid — which it is because `'static` outlives everything.

Comment: @BallpointBen Thank you for answering my question. So the compiler could have been designed to infer and elide for `f1` cases, but it was deliberately designed to error out. I'm curious if there was a reason for this.

Comment: The Rust compiler insists that all of a function's information be present in its signature. It is simply forbidden to use the function’s body to deduce anything about its signature. Whether good or bad, this is a decision implemented uniformly across Rust.

Answer (score 3):

> To my understanding f3 merely gives a name to the lifetime of the return value. It doesn't introduce any relationship to other defined lifetimes.

This is not true. `'a` is not just another name for `'static`; it is a caller-decided lifetime that can be any. The fact that the compiler allows assigning data with `'static` lifetime to `'a` is not because they're the same, but because `&'a str` is a subtype of `&'static str` - any lifetime is smaller than or equal to `'static`, so `'static` data is valid for any lifetime.

Comment: Does &str have no lifetime unless a caller-decided lifetime is specified?

Comment: @NaveenSanthanavel `&str`, like all references, always have a lifetime. It may be elided and inferred, but it's there.

Comment: If it does have a lifetime, then it must be a subtype of &'static str as well right? I'm curious why it is designed to fail if not explicitly annotated.

Comment: @NaveenSanthanavel Yes, any lifetime is a subtype of `'static`. I don't understand your question.